# ASP.Net application slow to load - VS2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

This is my set up on a stage server

compiled my web application

published website

copied the output directory from my machine to stage server

created domain account

created virtual site on a static IP

website runs under domain account created

impersonate set too true as windows integrated authentication is used with sql server

Now first time i hit my stage site, the page is slow to load which i understand, but subsequent request do take a while for the page to load.

planning to run wire shark to see what the traffic is. is there anything else that i should look for?

Note: My IIS and SQL are on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should run it through a profiler to see what it is spending so much time on.  SQL Server includes it's own nice query profiler, and if you want a free profiler for .net, there's [nprof](http://nprof.sourceforge.net/Site/Description.html).  If you want to pay for a profiler for .Net, and it's probably worth it in the long run, there's lots of good offerings available.

Answer (score 0):

Can you define slow? how many seconds?

Definitely check the queries to sql server to see what they are doing.

There is always task manager and take a look at cpu/memory. It is not hard to peg a single cpu for example. Anything else on the server?

When having problems I always like to have an empty aspx page just to eliminate other issues.

Comment: Data Dave: 5 seconds to load my start page. SQl execution plan is all good for the stored procedure and does not show anything abnormal.